# Events, methods using these events and inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am creating the program-side architecture of a software developped in WPF, I designed the architecture as being compliant with the MVVM pattern.

For many sakes (design, coherence, reusability, maintainability, scalability, etc) I created the class `BaseViewModel` implementing the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` and some other methods:

```
public class BaseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler property_changed;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { property_changed += value; }
        remove { property_changed -= value; }
    }

    //Here several methods using PropertyChanged and easing the usage of ViewModels

    public BaseViewModel() { }
}
```

The above-defined class `BaseViewModel` is used as a base class for all the other `ViewModel`s of the application (or, at least, is meant to be so), for example:

```
public class SampleViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //private PropertyChangedEventHandler property_changed;
    //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    //{
    //    add { property_changed += value; }
    //    remove { property_changed -= value; }
    //}

    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if(value != name)
            {
                 name = value;
                 var handler = PropertyChanged;
                 if(handler != null)
                 {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    private String name = "";

    public SampleViewModel ()
        : base() { }
}
```

I use the class `SampleViewModel` as the `DataContext` of `SampleUserControl` which bares a `DependencyProperty`:

```
public partial class SampleUserControl : UserControl
{
    #region ViewModel
    public SampleViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return view_model; }
    }
    private SampleViewModel view_model = new SampleViewModel();
    #endregion

    #region DependencyProperty
    public String Text
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(SampleUserControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(String.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                        new PropertyChangedCallback(TextPropertyChangedCallback)));
    private static void TextPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SampleUserControl sender = d as SampleUserControl;
        if (sender != null)
        {
            sender.ViewModel.Name = (String)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public SampleUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = ViewModel;
        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(ViewModel_PropertyChanged);
    }

    void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SampleViewModel viewmodel = sender as SampleViewModel;
        if (viewmodel != null)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "Name":
                    SetValue(TextProperty, viewmodel.Name);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To sum up, the data relative to `SampleUserControl` are contained at three locations : the instance of `SampleViewModel`, within `TextProperty` and within the property `Text` of a `TextBox` in the xaml part of `SampleUserControl`(this property `Text` is twoway-bound through `Binding` with the field `Name` of `ViewModel`).

To synchronize the three values, I added the methods `TextPropertyChangedCallback` and `ViewModel_PropertyChanged` which update the fields which need to be updated.

The above code works and the three above-mentionned locations are kept up-to-date, events fire and so on, things are fine when `SampleUsercontrol` is consumed with data-binding.

But `SampleViewModel` fires the event `BaseViewModel.PropertyChanged`, and since `BaseViewModel` is meant to be extensively used, I would like each `ViewModel` to have its own event `PropertyChanged`, at least in order to avoid overlapping events.

So I uncomment the code of `SampleViewModel` thus redefining the event `PropertyChanged` but it breaks down the synchronization between the field `Name` of the instance of `SampleViewModel` and the property `TextProperty` of `SampleUserControl`.

Am I making some mistakes on the conception side?
Do you have any guidance for me?
What is the best economic way of defining a different event `PropertyChanged` for each ViewModel inheriting from `BaseViewModel` while still using the general-purpose methods defined within that base class (such methods use `PropertyChanged`)?
(I would like to avoid having heavy pieces of code to copy-paste.)

I know that it is more about optimization, but such optimizations can make a difference between a slow software and a fast one. I am at the stage of code-factoring, so I fancy nicely-shaped, elegant and factorized code.

End of the day happening, I may miss some obvious solutions.

Thanks in advance for any clue,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Basically, I would double-check that you are doing your DC/DP on that user control correctly, and toss out any concept of multiple definitions of `PropertyChanged`

In detail:

1. You defined `PropertyChanged` in the base class, which is great. **There is no reason to ever redefine it *anywhere* else**. Really, you are just asking for trouble by doing this.
2. Related to that, you should *really* just make a method to do the event invocation rather than doing the whole `handler` bit in the settter. Insta-reduction of copy paste.
3. The fact that you are having to use `TextPropertyChanged` is a *huge* red flag here. Which relates to the real problem, that you are probably abusing your dependency property. DPs are used to allow *parent* controls to bind to a property of your user control. You typically won't use them in conjunction with a data context internal to the control because, as you have seen, keeping them in sync is a nightmare.
4. In general, user controls should only have their own data context if they are set up to stand apart from any other control (ie, a sub-view). If they are just a fancy control, then giving them a view model rarely gets you anything.

Comment: 1. Disagree. I prefer to not have inheritance for something that is actually a cross cutting concern, trying using AOP for `INPC` (see PropertyChanged.Fody).

Comment: @Aron Thats fine, if you don't want a base view model I won't argue with you. That said, you shouldn't be defining it in both the base and derived classes, as the base class one will be hidden and potentially cause you all sorts of weird problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "TL", "DR" and "DC/DP"? What do you mean by point 2? (Maybe I already implemented it in my above-mentioned and not-shown methods.) Regarding points 3 & 4, I have my reasons and the nightmare is over for me, since things are synchronized with the above code. Well, about the point 1, I have told that one event for each ViewModel would help me in the event managing, and taking over this challenge is the purpose of the current post. I don't know how to conceive the event management otherwise.

Comment: @JulienFerté "TL;DR" = "Too long, didn't read". DC = DataContext, DP = DependencyProperty. On two, I'm saying you have some boilerplate in your property setter that could go in a method, Regarding your response to points 1,3, and 4. The fact that you are doing it wrong, got it working, and discovered some problems with that approach should be telling you to *change the way you are doing it*. All you are doing by going down your current path is accruing technical debt.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? What is a better way of doing what I am doing?

Comment: @JulienFerté You are doing direct binding to a dependency property, and hiding a base implementation of `PropertyChanged`, Both of these things could be causing you numerous problems.